# 'FMDB.h' file not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

have been trying to import a header file for database.

I'm getting two errors.

```
'FMDB.h' file not found
```

and

```
 ailed to emit precompiled header '/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/zzzzzz- for bridging header '/Users/myname/Library/Autosave Information/zzzzzz/header.h'
```

The full path of FMDB.h is the below

```
/Users/myname/Library/Autosave Information/zzzzzz/fmdb/FMDB.h
```

In Objective-C Bridging Header : header.h

in the header file, the codes are :

```
 #ifndef Header_h
 #define Header_h
 #import "FMDB.h"

 #endif /* Header_h */
```

I set Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules as Yes. 
It didn't work out for me tho.

Comment: Are you using pods? I tried with pods and created a bridging header [YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h], Framework Modules as no (by default). And compiled, it is working fine. Build succeeded.

Comment: @RenukaPandey before you left the comment, I wasn't using cocoa pods, after I read your comment, I installed cocoa pods and i'm still facing the problem.

Comment: check my answer and follow the steps, it should work.

Comment: $(SRCROOT)/YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h

Answer (score 0):

Follow a few steps:

1. Rename your header to --> YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h
2. Check/Add Path of this header in your Build Setting --> Under Objective-CBridging Header (You may drag the file path)
3. Framework Modules as No

[image]

Then build, it should work. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently moved to new Mac book with Apple M1 Max chip and got the same error. I resolved it by removing arm64 from EXCLUDED_ARCHS in Build Settings.